# micro-service bounded context applies to infrastructure?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices, clean-architecture

My team own two micro-services, both hosted on AWS ECS. One service uses `aws redis`. For second service we need to implement lock mechanism for one endpoint. For that we need to store single key in redis. I propose to use same `aws redis infrastructure`. One point raise as its against `bounded context of first micro-service`.

**want to understand whether micro-service principals specially `bounded context` applies to underlying infrastructure.**

**Current Design**

[image: Current Design]

**Design if move Redis outside bounded context**
[image: moving redis outside bounded context]

Want to understand how bounded context related to infrastructure ?

Comment: Bounded Contexts define *knowledge boundaries* within your Domain Model.     A domain model, by definition, should not concern itself with architectural or deployment-time issues such as microservices or databases.    A domain model should focus on vocabulary and concepts which your business owners/subject matter experts use (from a non-technical perspective), and not technical/architectural concepts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as pointed out in the previous comment, there is no meaningful relation between bounded contexts (conceptual language boundaries) and infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for comment. was going through some posts, document & realize my diagram not correct. As @Ben Cottrell pointed-out DB, Redis, SNS/SQS are not part of bounded context. Thank Ben, Rik.